# Unexpected results when trying to prevent stack overflow

Tags: c, security, input, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to secure the fields below by specifying the width of the variables so that buffer overflow will not occur. I would prefer not to use fgets() as I am trying to write something within the specifications I have been given (using scanf).

The code is below:

```
char firstName[11], surName[21], job[16];

printf("Enter first name: ");
scanf("%10s", firstName);
printf("Enter surname: ");
scanf("%20s", surName);
printf("Enter job: ");
scanf("%15s", job);
```

So for input like so:

```
Enter first Name: UmbertoOverflow
/*surName gets skipped over*/
Enter job: janitor
```

I get:

```
First name: UmbertoOve
Surname: rflow
Job: janitor
```

It doesn't give me a chance to enter surname, it just fills with the remainder of the first name. This seems to be buffer overflow to me, so is there a way of using scanf without getting this result?

Comment: Buffer overflow and stack overflow are two different things.

Comment: What I mean is a stack based buffer overflow

Comment: That's also immaterial. Your code would have trouble even if the variables were static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%10s` for first name reads only first 10 characters - `UmbertoOve` - from input string and puts into `firstname`. The remaining - `rflow` - are still in the input buffer of program and `scanf()` for `surname` takes those characters. `'\n'` - or `Return - key` pressed while entering first name works as terminator and adds `rflow` in `surname`.

Its not buffer overflow, but expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, if it's not buffer overflow then I am happy enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bufferoverflow. It's just that scanf takes space or newline as the delimiter. Hence, the first scanf scans for 10 chars and the next continues to scan till it finds a space or '\n'.

Use

```
    scanf("%10s%*s", firstName);
    scanf("%20s%*s", surName);
    scanf("%15s%*s", job);
```